# Positivity in ternary rings of operators

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras

Recall that a ternary ring of operators (TRO) is a closed subspace $Z$ of $C^*$-algebra such that $xy^*z \in V$ for all $x,y,z \in Z$.

> How does one defines positivity/ordering in TRO?

I tried to find it in literature but could not find anything. Any reference or ideas?

Comment: What makes you believe that it defines an ordering?

Comment: To elaborate on @YCor's remark: the motivating example of a TRO (and in fact a concrete model for every TRO) is to take an off-diagonal "corner" of a $C^*$-algebra. So one should not expect any notion of positivity, because we are considering things like the $2\times 2$ matrix which as $1$ in the top-right corner and $0$ everywhere else

Comment: @YemonChoi: Apologies for late reply. What goes wrong if we try to define like this: Suppose $Z$ sits in $C^*-$ algebra $A$ then $x \in Z$ is positive if $x \in Z \cap A_{+}$

Comment: @YCor: I was wondering because TROs as far as I understand behaves “similar” to a $C^*-$ algebra and please read my other comment too.

Comment: If a sensible order is to be defined, one would expect it to be invariant under TRO isomorphisms (bijective linear maps preserving the ternary product $[x,y,z]:= xy^*z$).  However the proposed order $z\in Z\cap A_+$ does not satisfy this, a counter example being the off diagonal $2\times 2$ block in $M_4$ versus a diagonal $2\times 2$ block.

Comment: @Ruy: I’m bit confused because the same order which I gave has been proposed in Blecher’s paper titled “Open partial isometries and positivity in operator spaces“.

Comment: Dear @MathLover, I guess Blecher and Neal started out studying positivity in operator spaces (in reference [13]) and came to look at the case the operator space happens to be a TRO.  The order $Z_+ = Z\cap A_+$ is thus an example of what they were interested in.  Notice that in the remark just before their Corollary (2.2) they point out that $Z \cap Z^∗$ depends crucially on the particular ambient C*-algebra A chosen, as does the positive part.

Comment: @Ruy: thank you